# for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags): socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Tags: python

I'm new to python. i'm trying to send email using python. i have already enabled less secure app access and created app password but getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\My mask detection\xe1.py", line 11, in <module>
    with smtplib.SMTP('smtplib.gmail.com',587)as smtp:
  File "C:\Users\Adarsh C\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "C:\Users\Adarsh C\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\smtplib.py", line 336, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Adarsh C\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\smtplib.py", line 307, in _get_socket
    self.source_address)
  File "C:\Users\Adarsh C\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\socket.py", line 707, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Users\Adarsh C\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\socket.py", line 752, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

I don't understand what this error is referring to. i want to know where i have done wrong or do i want to do anything before i get in to code.

my code :

```
import smtplib
import os

with smtplib.SMTP('smtplib.gmail.com',587)as smtp:
    smtp.ehlo()
    smtp.starttls()
    smtp.ehlo()

    smtp.login('helpdeskadhi@gmail.com','pnfnvboatmczopkn')
    subject = "hello"
    body = "Nice to meet you!"

    msg = f'Subject: {subject}\n\n{body}'

    smtp.sendmail('helpdeskadhi@gmail.com','helpdeskadhi@gmail.com',msg)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. I fixed the indendation of your code, since it matters in Python.

Comment: socket.gaierror usually means it is looking up a hostname via DNS instead of ip address.  I see "smtplib.gmail.com" is the hostname being looked up which is invalid.  I think what you want is "smtp.gmail.com"

Answer (score 1):

```
smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer].

Answer (score 0):

```
from email.message import EmailMessage
import ssl
import smtplib


email_sender="xyz.gmail.com"
email_password="qwerty"
email_receiver="yur.gmail.com"
em = EmailMessage()
em['FROM']=email_sender
em['To']=email_receiver
em['subject']=subject
em.set_content(body)

context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com',465,context=context) as smtp:
    smtp.login(email_sender,email_password)
    smtp.sendmail(email_sender,email_rece iver,em.as_string())
```

Answer (score -1):

Not for the above question, but in general when this error occurs first, check your network connection.